# Is there a way to map PC "Options" key in vim?

Tags: key-bindings

Vim's help says Mac users can map command-key with `<D-`, so I wonder if PC users can map the Options key(between left ctrl&alt, hex code 0x66).

[image]

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's impossible without third party tools. That key is simply invisible to Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the results from pressing `o`, `<C-o>`, `<M-o>`, and `Windows + o` (in that order):

```
[~]% cat < /dev/stdin
o
^O
^[o
o
```

As you can see, a regular `o` and `Windows + o` aren't distinguished here.

As near as I can find, there is no way to fix this in either terminal Vim or Gvim :-( Many "solutions" simply remap the Windows key to Alt, but that is not a "solution" as far as I'm concerned...